# What minimum permissions and/or roles must a SQL Server login possess to be able to grant database db_datareader role to other logins?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

To delegate the ability for a security admin to add new SQL logins to the db_datareader role within a database, what are the least permissions and/or roles the security admin must possess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were a permission then you could use `WITH GRANT OPTION`, but it's not.

Assuming that you want to allow someone, or anyone in a particular Database-level Role, to perform this operation *but not* allow them to assign other Roles, then there is no permission or Role for that.

However, you can achieve this fine-grained "permission" via Module Signing. The minimum permission anyone needs is `EXECUTE` on a Stored Procedure that you write to do nothing more than add a Login or Role to that specific Database Role.

This is similar to what I outlined in the following answer:

[What minimum permissions do I need to provide to a user so that it can check the status of SQL Server Agent Service?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/what-minimum-permissions-do-i-need-to-provide-to-a-user-so-that-it-can-check-the/103275#103275)

except in your particular case it is even easier since no server-level permissions are needed. Just do the following:

1. Create a Stored Procedure that has an input parameter for the Principal name, and simply adds that Database Principal to the `db_datareader` Database-level Role
2. Create a Certificate in that same DB
3. Create a User, in that same DB, from that Certificate
4. Add the Certificate-based User to the `db_owner` Database-level Role
5. Sign the Stored Procedure (from Step 1) with that Certificate
6. Grant any User who should be able to do this `EXECUTE` permission on that Stored Procedure

---

For the sake of completeness:

Technically speaking, you could add `EXECUTE AS 'dbo'` to the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, but that uses Impersonation which has issues of its own, and is less secure than the Module Signing approach I described above.

Comment: Question is not about executing store procedure but it is about adding members in role that you are already a member.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I just added some verbiage at the top of my answer to clarify that I was addressing the intent of the question, not the literal wording. The O.P. certainly appears to want to allow someone to allow others into a specific Role instead of having the ability to add to all Roles, or all user-defined Roles.

Comment: @Solomon Rutzky Correctly interpreted. The trick is now to create a single stored proc in master that dynamically empowers the restricted security admin to be able to add a login to the db_datareader role in any database.

Comment: @Guessed Well, that assumes that the Login has a corresponding User in that DB. But either way, that is still easy. Just needs to be Dynamic SQL and needs to be a server-level permission. There might be a server-level role for security that allows for this. Else might need to use `sysadmin`. Just be sure to check the input params for DatabaseName and UserName to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: @Solomon Rutzky sysadmin is not permitted. The intent is to empower help desk techs with the ability to add either Windows or SQL logins, map them to dbs, and add these db users to the db_datareader role only, in any db on a SQL Server. All this, while containing their powers to a minimum.

Comment: @Guessed _That_ is the beauty of Module Signing: permissions are given to the code, not to people! The existing security infrastructure is such that permissions need to be attached to something, which is why one creates a Login and/or User from the Certificate (or Asymmetric Key). The Certificate- or Key- based Login/User merely contains permissions that get applied to code that is signed with the same Cert or Key. But they can't log in or be impersonated. This is why it is the most secure means of given granular permissions. One proc could do all of those steps without giving anyone sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Microsoft documentation on database level roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles) a user within a database must be a member of either the db_owner or db_securityadmin roles to execute `ALTER ROLE` commands.

It is also possible per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql to grant the permission of `ALTER` on a role, or `ALTER ANY ROLE` to allow membership to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change membership for a fixed database role you have to be a member of `db_owner` fixed database role.

In order to change membership for a user-defined database role as a minimum you need to have `alter any role` privilege.

It will be a long example but hopefully you can follow this.

Set up.

```
USE [Master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [TestPerm];
GO
CREATE LOGIN testPerm1 WITH PASSWORD = 'testPerm1###',DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO
CREATE LOGIN testPerm2 WITH PASSWORD = 'testPerm2###',DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO
USE  [TestPerm]
GO
CREATE USER testPerm1;
GO
CREATE USER testPerm2;
GO
ALTER ROLE [DB_DATAREADER] ADD MEMBER testPerm1;
GO
GRANT ALTER ANY ROLE  TO testPerm1;
GO
```

Now run as `testPerm1` user and try to add `testPerm2` user to the fixed database role `db_datareader`.

```
USE  [TestPerm]
GO
EXECUTE AS USER='testPerm1'
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();  
ALTER ROLE [DB_DATAREADER] ADD MEMBER testPerm2;
REVERT;
```

Getting the following error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 Cannot alter the role
>   'DB_DATAREADER', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

Add user `testPerm1` as a member of `db_securityadmin` role and try to add `testPerm2` user to the fixed database role `db_datareader`.  You will get the same error as previous step.

```
 USE [testPerm]
 GO
 ALTER ROLE [db_securityadmin] ADD MEMBER testPerm1;
 GO
 EXECUTE AS USER='testPerm1'
 SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();  
 ALTER ROLE [DB_DATAREADER] ADD MEMBER testPerm2;
 REVERT;
```

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 Cannot alter the role
>   'DB_DATAREADER', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

Adding `testPerm1` user as a member of `db_owner` fixed database role.

```
USE [testPerm]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER testPerm1;
GO
```

Now try to add `testPerm2` user to the fixed database role `db_datareader`. Command will succeed.

```
 USE [testPerm]
 GO
 EXECUTE AS USER='testPerm1'
 SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();  
 ALTER ROLE [DB_DATAREADER] ADD MEMBER testPerm2;
 REVERT;
```

Lets check the permission required to add members to user-defined database role.

Create a new role and add `testPerm1` user to this role.

```
USE [TestPerm]
GO
CREATE ROLE [testPermission]
GO
ALTER ROLE [DB_DATAREADER] ADD MEMBER testPerm1;
GO
```

Remove `testPerm1` user from `db_owner` and `db_securityadmin` role.

```
USE [TestPerm]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] DROP MEMBER testPerm1;
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_securityadmin] DROP MEMBER testPerm1;
GO
```

Try to modify user defined database role `testPermission` by user `testPerm1` and it will be successful because `testPerm` user still had `alter any role` privilege.

```
EXECUTE AS USER='testPerm1'
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();  
ALTER ROLE [testPermission] ADD MEMBER testPerm2;
REVERT;
```

Revoke `alter any role` privilege for `testPerm1` user.

```
USE [TestPerm]
GO
REVOKE ALTER ANY ROLE  TO testPerm1;
GO
```

Try to modify user defined database role `testPermission` by user `testPerm1`, you get the error message:

```
EXECUTE AS USER='testPerm1'
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();  
ALTER ROLE [testPermission] DROP MEMBER testPerm2;
REVERT;
```

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Cannot alter the role
>   'testPermission', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

Clean up code.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'TestPerm'
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestPerm] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE [master]
GO
DROP DATABASE [TestPerm]
GO
DROP LOGIN [testPerm1]
GO
DROP LOGIN [testPerm2]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I could comment on all the above answers one by one but I think i'd better write here one compact answer. The question is about adding a user to a **FIXED DATABASE ROLE** `db_datareader` and that is the key. From [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql) we know that

> Adding members to **fixed database roles** requires membership in the
>   `db_owner` fixed database role.

And since the OP asked about **the least permission**, and membership in `db_owner` database role is the maximum you can have within a database, the only possible solution here is signed procedure.
So I upvote **Solomon Rutzky** answer