# Stored Procedure Execute as Owner Close Database Connections Not Working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, connections, impersonation

I created a stored procedure to allow users to Close All Db connections in the QA environment.  I am SA and created the procedure.

When I modify the SP , run it Without 'Execute as Owner', I get results.
When I add 'Execute as Owner', I do not receive any results.

Trying to understand why.

```
create procedure [dbo].[DatabaseConnectionClose]
    @DatabaseName varchar(255)
with execute as owner
as


DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';  
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), session_id) + ';'  
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE database_id  = db_id(@DatabaseName)

select @kill as CloseConnectionScript

EXEC(@kill);
```

Comment: The script you have is inferior because (a) there's a more efficient way to achieve the same thing and (b) `database_id` is unreliable since cross-database queries and locks can exist. `SET @kill = N'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'`

Answer (score 8):

Using the `EXECUTE AS` clause of the `CREATE {module_type}` statement is impersonation, but only at the Database level. The owner is "dbo" (in this case, at least), but that is just a User; a Database-level principal. The `KILL` command requires an Instance-level permission. By default, when using Database-level impersonation (`EXECUTE AS` clause *or* `EXECUTE AS USER` statement), the process is quarantined to the current Database, even if that User maps to a Login (by having the same SID) that has the appropriate permission. Because of this restriction, the process is not allowed to reach up to the Instance to check Instance-level permissions.

To do this properly:

1. Get rid of `EXECUTE AS`
2. Implement this using Module Signing:

   [Safely and Easily Use High-Level Permissions Without Granting Them to Anyone: Server-level](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/02/15/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-server-level/) (blog post of mine; external, but has better explanation)

   [What minimum permissions do I need to provide to a user so that it can check the status of SQL Server Agent Service?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103275/30859) (one of my answers, here on DBA.SE)

   The only permission you should need to grant to the Certificate-based Login is: `ALTER ANY CONNECTION` (as per the documentation for [KILL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql))

For more info on module signing, please visit: [Module Signing Info](https://modulesigning.info/)

---

Also, in addition to the excellent point made by Aaron Bertrand in a comment on the question, you need to be careful not to kill sessions for legitimate processes, such as SQL Server Agent, etc. You should filter on at least the `program_name` column of `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, if not also `login_name` (and possibly others).

However, if `ALTER DATABASE [{db_name}] SET...` ends up being the way to proceed, then use the following post as a guide since you won't be concerned with Instance-level permissions in that case:

[Safely and Easily Use High-Level Permissions Without Granting Them to Anyone: Database-level](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/03/05/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-database-level/)